# How to refactor namespaces in C# without affecting other projects?

Tags: c#, namespaces, migration, refactoring, compatibility

I have a Nuget package where I started out by keeping most of my classes and interfaces in the base namespace. Over time the default namespace has become cluttered with a lot of classes that are independent from each other and I would like to move them to their own namespaces. As an example I would like to convert the below without affecting existing users of the projects:

```
 namespace WebTestSuite
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Public test result properties
     /// </summary>
     public interface ITestResult
     {
           /* Interface definition here */
     }
 }
```

To:

```
 namespace WebTestSuite.Results
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Public test result properties
     /// </summary>
     public interface ITestResult
     {
           /* Interface definition here */
     }
 }
```

The end goal is to allow me to refactor namespaces in my project, and when users get the latest version of the package, their references to WebTestSuite.ITestResult will automatically be updated to WebTestSuite.Results.ITestResult.

I was thinking I could write a migration script, but wasn't sure if that was necessary or if there are any frameworks or anything that would make this easier. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good one - interested in what answers come up. What I've seen from library/api providers is a _version_ change/upgrade + release notes/notices/deprecations, so those with dependencies can adjust (or not). If it's critical (e.g. security), a timeline to "upgrade" is provided.

Comment: May not apply in your case, since you've mentioned "naming/namespaces" - but if it were _functional_ you could treat the "legacy" code as "pointers" - re: legacy users still call the same methods and expect the same results (regardless of _how_ you handle internally).

Comment: @EdSF Combining your two answers might be a good idea. I could possibly create a duplicate interface in the new namespace, then update the original interface to extend the new interface and mark the old one as deprecated. I could then note it in the release notes, and remove the deprecated code in a future release. This might get messy though and I'm not positive it would work or possible repercussions.

Answer (score -1):

You can try Resharper. It will provide lots of control over code refactoring with minimal effort. 
With resharper you can follow [this guideline](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Move__Type_to_Another_Namespace.html).

Comment: I am more worried about other users projects that would be effected by the refactor. For example, if I refactored my code as I did above, my project would be refactored fine, however, users who have references to the WebTestSuite.ITestResult interface will no longer be able to find the ITestResult interface. My goal is to have some sort of way of updating all references from WebTestSuite.ITestResult to WebTestSuite.Results.ITestResult without requiring other projects to update their references manually.

Comment: When you change namchaespace using resharper it will change the references of others classes as usual. You have no need to change them manually.

Comment: @Fagun Resharper only change references it finds in _your_ project or solution (_your_ can refer to individual or team, say in a source controlled environment). The OP _"has a NUGET package" (used by anyone with the dependency)_